# Definition of friendship in Islam

Tags: quran, hadith, practical-islam, sunnah, friendship

Is there a solid definition of friendship in Islam, and way of making friends in Islam?

Are there specific references that we are abid to for making friends?

Please referencing Quran and Hadith with your answer.  Jazak-allah Khair!

Comment: This question seems to lack any sort of focus or research effort: (a) Why would you even think Islam would even *have* a "solid definition of friendship"?  (b) What, if anything, are you looking for that can't be found in a [basic Google search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=friendship%20in%20islam)? (c) What *exactly* are you asking that makes this any more answerable than a vague "What does Islam say about [topic]" question? (see meta discussion: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1518/22)

Answer (score 2):

Salaamu alaikum
Regarding friendship in Islam, i'm not sure regarding the 'solid definition' part, but regarding  the Prophet, peace be upon him, (for example) i suppose his companions would have been considered his friends. The reason why i mentioned that is because this would then mean that your 'friends' would be those you spend your time with.In saying that however, you do eed to be careful about the friends you choose, as they have a huge impact on the way you think, act, dress, etc. regarding islamic evidence, there is quite a few, but some that i found include:
the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said, "A person follows the ways and conducts of his friends." - See more at: http://www.iisna.com/articles/general/companionship-and-friendship-in-islam/#sthash.8At6xVqq.dpuf

alos, there is a quranic verse that states "O woe is me! Would that I had not taken such a one as my friend." this refers to the person on the day of judgement who had taken  a friend that deviated them away from the true path. In other words, your friends should benefit you regarding your religion, that is what true friendship, because if you think about it, that is what we are living for, right? (you get what i mean)